# Azure SQL, MySQL/Postgres SQL How HADR for Postgres SQL build on REDHAT Linux server

Tags: redhat, azure, postgresql

How can i design **HADR** solution in **Azure** Cloud  for my **Postgrel SQL server** which is build on **Redghat Linux system.** **(IAAS)**

I have referred HADR for SQL database in Azure, its pretty clear and i know that Azure PAAS service for My SQL and Postgres SQL in preview which comes with HADR solution. **https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-high-availability-dr#geo-replication-support**

However my Postgres SQL server will be deployed as Azure IAAS **not PAAS**
Please let me know HADR solution for my Postgres SQL in Redhat Linux (Azure IAAS).

Thanks in advance.